# How can I put an outline rectangle underneath an image as shown in the following image

Tags: css, html, image

Probably my question is fairly simple and I apologize for this but started shortly with html and css and I still do not have much practice.
I would like to know how I can put a rectangle underneath an image (jpeg or css) as shown in the following image:

[image: My problem]

Comment: You can draw a rectangles in SVG format from your CSS file, or play with div's having a border. You will also to write the rectangle below the picture using the Z-index and absolute positions to make the div's and/or the svg drawings overlap each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, is by using a separate `div` for the border: Setting `position: absolute;` to the image and the div for the border, and using `z-index` to put the image on top of the border div.

You have to use a container div to embrace both, the image and the border div. This container gets `position: relative` (to set the `position: absolute` of the child elements into effect) and needs to have the dimensions of the entire cluster of child elements.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 120px;
}

.container div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.image {
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.rect {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>
  <div class="rect">
  </div>
</div>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would post this answer when there is already a better solution answered. Using `pseudoelement` is the correct approach here.

Comment: Simply because I was starting to write this answer, before any answer was posted.

Comment: Fair enough - On the bright side, it gives another approach and should he want to add more content into the box as well, it would be possible using this :)

Comment: And I just figured out, that the "better solution" is not working without providing height and width in the container div.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap `img` in a `div` and add a `psuedoelement` to that `div`.

Using a `pseudoelement` means you don't need to declare the height and width of the `img` container.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
  top: 3rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://unsplash.it/400"></div>
```

A more complete layout example...

```css
section {
  padding: 3rem 4.5rem;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 3rem 1rem 0;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

figure:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.5rem;
  bottom: 1.5rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure><img src="https://unsplash.it/260"></figure>
  <h3>A Title</h3>
  <h5>Subtitle subtitle subtitle subtitle</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine.

Comment: @DragonBorn Not necessarily, it's just one approach. OPs layout may favour your approach

Comment: I just tried this solution, and it does not work without providing width and height for the container div. The text will and in the border, as the container has only the size of the image, not considering the pseudoelement.

Comment: @MichaelScheffenacker By container, I mean a div containing the image and nothing else.

Comment: @sol I think the solution is very good. But I would suggest to add the size to the containing div, to prevent the text (or other following elements) from reaching into the border.

Comment: @MichaelScheffenacker I've added a more complete example. The image container just needs a margin to ensure it doesn't clash with the text.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic example on how you can add a rectangle underneath an image using css.
Check the snippet.

```css
div { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: -10;
}

img { 
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uuuploads/landscape-photography/landscape-photography-23.jpg" />
<div></div>
```